# Novice: Items set to zero

Tags: java

I've just been coding for the past few months, and am just getting started on Java.

I'm getting these weird error messages when I'm testing some of my code.

In one of my exercises, I have this class WeatherRecord. I define it like this:

```
class WeatherRecord {
  Date d;
  double precipitation; 
  TemperatureRange today;
  TemperatureRange normal;
  TemperatureRange record;

  WeatherRecord(Date d, double precipitation, TemperatureRange today, 
  TemperatureRange normal, TemperatureRange record) {
    d = this.d;
    precipitation = this.precipitaiton;
    today = this.today;
    normal = this.normal;
    record = this.record;
  }
```

Seems dandy. I also have some comments and methods, but I left those out.

Then, later on in my examples, I make an example, like this:

```
WeatherRecord record2 = new WeatherRecord(this.date2, 0.24,
      this.temp2, this.tempNormal, this.coldTemp);
```

Where date2, temp2, and all that stuff are previously defined.

I then use a tester library just to check to make sure that precipitation is set to 0.24 (since one of my methods wasn't working earlier, so I was checking):

```
 boolean test(Tester t) {
   return t.checkExpect(this.record2.precipitaiton, 0.24); 

 }
```

And my console tells me that the actual value was 0.0, rather than .24. I'm consistently getting this sort of error on a lot of different exercises.

Does anything immediately stand out to y'all that I am doing wrong? Is there any more information I should provide?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`d = this.d;` this chunk of code should be the other way around. `this.d = d;`

as well as the others.

`this.var` means the object's `var` while the variable you receive into the method or constructor doesn't start with `this`

Comment: That absolutely makes sense. I'll have to remember that the order matters. Thanks!

Edit: Will accept this answer once it allows me to (7 minutes). Still getting used to this website. Thanks again.

Comment: If you don't want to get confused, you can always change the variable name you receive into your constructor/method but this is not usually convention. Good luck!